# Any performance gains from having identical clustered and nonclustered indexes on table on different filegroups?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index, nonclustered-index, filegroups, clustered-primary-key

I am attempting to rearchitect our MSSQL database such that we have two filegroups, one for data, on a 15K HDD, `primary`, and one for indexes on a separate SSD, `indexes`, in order to realize some performance gains (which I read could be [debatable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/when-should-nonclustered-indexes-be-stored-on-separate-filegroups), but I think in my case it is true).

I would ideally like to create a table on `primary` with an index on `indexes` to realize these gains, however the PK constraint happens to contain the same columns we would normally query, therefore the *clustered* PK index **must**, by definition also live on `primary`.

Would I still realize any performance gains if I created a nonclustered index containing the same columns as the PK on the `indexes` FG?

Comment: Can you clarify if the nonclustered index colums would ONLY be on the key columns of the primary key (and I'm assuming clustered index)?

Comment: Also, unless you're using direct attach storage (or your SAN has a much higher tier of storage you can pin the nonclustered indexes to), I'd skip separating anything.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik that is correct in that that was my intention.  If my primary key was on columns A, B, and C, users will query the database specifying A, B, C, and also pulling in additional aggregate columns grouped by A, B, and C, generally.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik it's direct attached storage.

Comment: Right, so, if your nonclustered indexes aren't covering, and your queries need to do lookups back to the clustered indexes anyway, you kinda lose out to some degree on the gains from separating. This could totally be doable with a small, predictable workload. Is your data in the billions of rows?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik yes just over 1 billion rows.

Comment: The performance gain (or not) depends on your query mix. Sequential scan performance on HDDs degrades considerably when interrupted by other IO, particularly with a lot of other concurrent random activity, causing unproductive seek time. Not so much an issue with SSD. Consider those factors in your indexing and filegroup placement strategy.

Comment: My first step would be to pack as much RAM in the server as possible so that disk isn't as much of a factor. Separating data out rarely gets anyone the kind of performance increase they're looking for.